# Many independent pseudorandom graphs each with same arbitrary y for any input x

Tags: python, algorithm, random, python-3.4

By 'graph' I mean 'function' in the mathematical sense, where you always find one unchanging y value per x value.

Python's `random.Random` class's `seed` behaves as the x-coordinate of a random graph and each new call to `random.random()` gives a new random graph with all new x-y mappings.

Is there a way to directly refer to `random.Random`'s nth graph, or in other words, the nth value in a certain seed's series without calling `random.random()` n times?

I am making a set of classes that I call `Transformers` that take any (x,y) coordinates as input and output another pair of (x,y) coordinates. Each transformer has two methods: `transform` and `untransform`. One of the transformers that I want adds a random value to the input y coordinate depending on the the input x coordinate. Say that I then want this transformer to `untransform(x, y)`, now I need to subtract the same value I added from y if x is the same. This can be done by setting the seed to the same value it had when I added to y, so acting like the x value. Now say that I want two different instances of the transformer that adds random values to y. My question is about my options for making this new random transformer give different values than the first one.

Comment: So you're saying the graphs aren't random, but rather you're randomly selecting amongst a set of deterministic graphs?

Comment: i think the OP is saying that for whatever reason, they want fast access to some arbitrary nth term of the series for a given seed. & have some idea of how the algo works (ie: same x seed gives same nth term in that series) yet not enough of an idea to realise that the entropic nature of the algo actually precludes those requirements :)

Comment: NB: the reason he probably wrote down all the graph theory stuff, is cos he was terrified of getting down-voted by all the pointy-heads; which sadly he failed to do in any case lol ~&ftr, i think it's a reasonable enough question; improved only by a brief explanation of why fast access to a nth term is necessary :D ~btw @pjs : pseudorandom number generators certainly /are/ deterministic ;)

Comment: @violet313: Victor used the term "random" as a shorthand, so I did too. I'm fully aware that `random` is backed by a PRNG. I'm trying to get a clarification from Victor as to which part(s) of the problem are dependent on calls to `random`, and which aren't.

Comment: You're right! This is my second try asking this question and I not only got downvoted the first time (waaa!), but closed as a duplicate to 'How do you get the same random series twice?', a subtly, but importantly different goal than mine. Trying to make it clear that I was asking something different than that, I have posed the random module in the exact (but apparently evil) way that I am looking at it for my purposes: as a collection of pseudorandom graphs.

Comment: @pjs, I am not randomly selecting the graphs. I want to take the different graphs as objects that I can use. The first number that each seed gives you when you call random.random() is the first graphs. The second number for each seed is the second graph, etc. I want to have each graph as an object.

Comment: @pjs ah! ok, it's just that Victor was only describing how the python prng works in terms of graph theory, so of course the graphs he's talking about are deterministic, &so at first your comment didn't really make much sense to me ~all perfectly clear now however lol.

Comment: @Victor You need to be more careful with your wording, lack of clarity often leads to downvotes and closure of questions here. You wrote "The first number that each seed gives you when you call random.random() is the first graphs", but that makes no sense.  A number is not a graph.  I _think_ you're trying to say that the numbers from `random.random()` are used to select a graph from a set of graphs, but I don't want to put words in your mouth. Is that what you meant? I'm still not getting it.

Comment: @pjs, I said that the first number FOR EACH SEED was the first graph. What I did fail to communicate was that I really meant 'for each seed that is a float' because Python can take any hashable object as a seed whereas a mathematical fn requires a number. Thank you for helping me clarify this.

Comment: @Victor Saying a number *is* a graph makes no sense at all to me. If you mean that the first number produced using a graph object as the seed *maps to* that graph object, then say that! If that's the case you're just using the PRNG as a hashing function.

Comment: @pjs, overcoming ambiguity is one of the great challenges of communication. Sorry I'm failing to predict & disambiguate how your specialized knowledge inclines you to interpret my words, but I assure you I have said what I mean, even if with naivety to many possible interpretations. I am exploring ideas for simulating a random graph or many such. Imagine taking a piece of graph paper and flicking paint at it--a very informal analogy. More formally, I am looking for ways to output one random-like y value within any range, say 0 to 1, for each infinite x (dx) value, from -infinity to infinity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Python 3.4 apparently removes `jumpahead`, here's some code that implements a convenient pseudorandom dictionary.

```
from hashlib import sha256 as _sha256
from hmac import HMAC as _HMAC
from math import ldexp as _ldexp
from os import urandom as _urandom
from sys import byteorder as _byteorder

class PRF():

    def __init__(self):
        digestmod = _sha256
        self._h = _HMAC(_urandom(digestmod().block_size), digestmod=digestmod)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        h = self._h.copy()
        h.update(repr(key).encode())
        b = h.digest()
        return _ldexp(int.from_bytes(b, _byteorder), (len(b) * (- 8)))
```

Example usage:

```
>>> import prf
>>> f = prf.PRF()
>>> f[0]
0.5414241336009658
>>> f[1]
0.5238549618249061
>>> f[1000]
0.7476468534384274
>>> f[2]
0.899810590895144
>>> f[1]
0.5238549618249061
```

Comment: This seems to do what I needed (and much more), Thank you!

Comment: @Victor I made a couple of improvements.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to directly refer to random.Random's nth graph, or in other words, the nth value in a certain seed's series without calling random.random() n times?

Yes, sort of; you use [`Random.jumpahead()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/random.html#random.jumpahead). There aren't really separate functions/graphs, though -- there's only one sequence generated by the PRNG -- but you can get into it at any point.

You seem to be still working on the same problem as [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515474/for-python-3-4-how-can-i-get-the-same-random-number-every-time-i-pass-the-same), and the code I posted in a comment there should cover this:

```
from random import Random

class IndependentRepeatableRandom(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.randgen = Random()
        self.origstate = self.randgen.getstate()

    def random(self, val):
        self.randgen.jumpahead(int(val))
        retval = self.randgen.random()
        self.randgen.setstate(self.origstate)
        return retval
```

Comment: I was curious about what `jumpahead` does, [so I looked](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/random.py): it's computing a SHA512 and feeding it into some C that allegedly shuffles the bits of the Mersenne Twister state. At that price, one might consider using an [HMAC](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/hmac.html) straight up, which has the bonus of being cryptographically secure but the drawback of being less convenient.

Comment: Interesting, @DavidEisenstat. I suspect that the OP is not concerned about security based on his About Me. It's not badly thought though, and actually it looks like `jumpahead()` was removed sometime between 3.0 and 3.4?! So your idea or something like it may be necessary...

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I see that `jumpahead` would do the equivalent of what I was asking since you pointed out that Python's Random class is actually a single discrete series that simply starts at different indices depending on the seed rather than many infinite-resolution graphs. Thank you for helping me see that. The larger the series is, the less this distinction would matter though.

Comment: It should be big enough for your needs, @Victor: there's a few quadrillion elements in the series, and it takes a Very Long time to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're probably going to need to come up with some more detailed requirements but yes, there are ways:

1. pre-populate a dictionary with however many terms in the series you require for a given seed and then at run-time simply look the `nth` term up.
2. if you're not fussed about the seed values and/or do not require some `n` terms for any given seed, then find a O(1) way of generating different seeds and only use the first term in each series.

Otherwise, you may want to stop using the built-in python functionality & devise your own (more predictable) algo.

**EDIT wrt the new infos:**

Ok. so i also looked at your profile & so you are doing something (musical?) other than any new crypto thing. if that's the case, then it's unfortunately mixed blessings, because while you don't require security, you also still won't want (audible) patterns appearing. so you unfortunately probably do still need a strong prng.

> One of the transformers that I want adds a random value to the input y
>   coordinate depending on the the input x coordinate

It's not yet clear to me if there is actually any real requirement for y to depend upon x...

> Now say that I want two different instances of the transformer that
>   adds random values to y. My question is about my options for making
>   this new random transformer give different values than the first one.

..because here, i'm getting the impression that all you really require is for two different instances to be different in some random way.

But, assuming you have some object containing tuple (x,y) and you really do want a `transform` function to randomly vary y for the same x; and you want an `untransform` function to quickly undo any transform operations, then why not just keep a stack of the state changes throughout the lifetime of any single instance of an object; and then in the `untransform` implementation, you just pop the last transformation off the stack ?

Comment: Thanks for offering these. I didn't originally give enough detail to exclude your first suggestion, but I can't take it because, as I will soon explain in an edit above, I need the y of ANY x, not just a known handful. As far as the second idea goes, if I get what you mean, then I have imagined doing what I believe you're suggesting by just multiplying the seed of each pseudorandom graph by the clock when it was initialized. I had just hoped that since there were already many 'graphs' that I could just access these directly without altering the first 'graph'.

Comment: I believe that even a weak PRNG would not be audibly distinguishable from true random numbers, but I can't say I know that by any means! I was never focused on the quality of the randomness, although there is a purist part of me that is pleased by the thought. My interest here has been to see the possible ways to get the same pseudorandom y value every time I input a particular given x value, but also to have an arbitrarily large number of objects that give a different set of y values in this manner.

Comment: coolio. i'm glad you got your algo in the end ~i'm having fun with [lmms](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/home.php) in my downtime; &i seriously hope that in the fullness of time, you consider making a nice o/s plugin so i can fully appreciate your (purist) efforts, whatever they may be ;)

Comment: I clicked on the LMMS link... the software you can get for free these days! By the way, I think if you had not participated in answering this question, it would have fizzled out again because when it was largely (and understandably) being dismissed, you were the first person to recognize any substance in it despite my difficulty conveying my goals both succinctly and clearly. Thanks very much for that!

Comment: lol de rien -just remember this post when you have a SO big rep & so go easy on the noobs; cos they may not be stupid =) ~& that software is only free cos lots of kind clever folk gave it up innit?! =)